# Neo4j HA backup fails after first succeeding

Tags: neo4j

I have successfully setup a neo4j 3-instance HA cluster using version 2.0.2 enterprise, but I'm having a problem using the built in backup script (../bin/neo4j-backup).

I manually run:

`./bin/neo4j-backup -from ha://10.6.10.48:5001 -to /usr/local/neo4j/backup`

...on the master, and it works fine the first time, dumping the data into ../neo4j/backup.

Subsequent tries with the same command yields only this on the command line:

`Could not find backup server in cluster neo4j.ha at 10.6.10.48:5001, operation timed out`

and this in messages.log:

```
2014-04-29 17:08:00.919+0000 DEBUG [o.n.c.p.c.ClusterState$4]: ClusterState: entered-[configurationRequest]->entered from:cluster://10.6.10.48:5002 conversation-id:-1/8# payload:-1:cluster://0.0.0.0:5002/?name=Backup
2014-04-29 17:08:00.922+0000 ERROR [o.n.c.c.NetworkSender]: Receive exception:
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.cleanUpWriteBuffer(AbstractNioWorker.java:409) ~[netty-3.6.3.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.writeFromUserCode(AbstractNioWorker.java:127) ~[netty-3.6.3.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:83) ~[netty-3.6.3.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:725) ~[netty-3.6.3.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.doEncode(OneToOneEncoder.java:71) ~[netty-3.6.3.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.handleDownstream(OneToOneEncoder.java:59) ~[netty-3.6.3.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:704) ~[netty-3.6.3.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:671) ~[netty-3.6.3.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.write(AbstractChannel.java:248) ~[netty-3.6.3.Final.jar:na]
        at org.neo4j.cluster.com.NetworkSender$2.run(NetworkSender.java:266) ~[neo4j-cluster-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_15]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_15]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0_15]
```

(exception repeats every 5 seconds for awhile)

relevant neo4j.properties values:

```
online_backup_enabled=true
online_backup_server=127.0.0.1:6362
ha.cluster_server=10.6.10.48:5001
```

I've checked all firewall settings for all instances.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Check the console.log to make sure that the cluster is still up, and that the server in question is still available as a backup server?

Comment: Yes, the cluster is still up and that instance is still listed as the backup instance.  Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running a online backup versus `single://<host>` in general way more easy compared to `ha://<host>`. From a functional view there  is no advantage of `ha://`.

So you might change

online_backup_server=10.6.10.48:6362

and then run

```
/bin/neo4j-backup -single ha://10.6.10.48:6362 -to /usr/local/neo4j/backup
```

Comment: Yes, running the backup in single mode works every time. Thanks!